# Putting boolean in SQL query WHERE without ARRAY

Tags: php, sql, arrays, where-clause

I am using using SMF right now, and I have some problem about the SMCFUNC's WHERE logic.

**The Story:**
I want to assign additional id_group based on karma_good. Lets say if your karma_good is between 99 and 200, I will assign you(and all other users with karma_good between 99 and 200) ID_GROUP number 20 (for example).

**What I Did:**
I made an PHP file, and put these code below into that PHP and execute it directly

```
$result = $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
                UPDATE {db_prefix}members
                SET id_group = 20
                WHERE karma_good > 99 && karma_good < 200
                ',
                );
```

**What Happened:**
It fails. I think it is because there is no ARRAY to it...but I am not sure if I do even have to use the ARRAY in here. Well I could do it directly in the SQL by putting in trigger, so that everytime the database is updated, it will assign ID_group with the condition I mentioned above, but then I don't know what code I should put in, and that's not what I am asking here:D.

**Closing:**
Is there something that I miss above? May be wrong boolean logic in WHERE? May be I must put in ARRAY? Or may the can never be boolean logic in WHERE function?

Thanks!!

Comment: why would you need an array ? just use `WHERE karma_good BETWEEN 99 AND 200`  You'll probably find your error is the {db_prefix} bit not being put into your sql query because your query is in single quotes. but it could also be your lack of 3rd parameter being put into the db_query key `,);` should probably be `,'');`

Comment: @Dave your answer has just saved the day!:D. Should have put that double single quote after the coma before the ");" and I just know that you could just use "BETWEEN" instead of putting that universal boolean logic (&&, >, < and so on). Thanks so much.~~

Comment: @MarcB If I want to give users with karma_good between 99 and 200 an ID_GROUP = 20 then these users are sets of data right?That's why I thought lacking ARRAY could be the problem. It is under smf_members library in phpmyadmin. This fails, doesn't change anything when I checked the SQL, but now it is working:D.Thanks and well I should get a dog to kick first before I ask here haha. Sometimes it is so annoying when a code doesn't work:D